# How can I find if an element of one enum is contained in the other?

Tags: java

Good afternoon.

I would like to ask the question about Java enum: if there are two enums

`enum Elements_1 {aaa, bbb, ccc};`

and

`enum Elements_2 {ccc, ddd, eee};`

How can we figure out if an element of one is contained in the other?

Thank You.

Comment: There is no _contains_ relation here. Do you mean if two enum constants have the same name? What value would that have? What are you trying to use that comparison for?

Comment: never. Even if the identifiers are the same `Elements_1.ccc` and `Elements_2.ccc` are different things.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, Yes, I do agree with you - it's a particular constant, actually. I would like to use it for a boolean variable - if they do have the same named constant - it becomes 'true' and vice versa.

Comment: That's not a valid use of enums. You can compare the `toString` or `name` values of constants, but that has about as much value as comparing a "driver" from a golf-club set with a bus operator because that's also a "driver". It's better not to abandon type safety and good sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if checking the names of your enumeration is what you need:

```
List<String> enumA = Arrays.stream(Elements_1.values()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> enumB = Arrays.stream(Elements_2.values()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toList());
enumA.retainAll(enumB);
```

enumA will show you the intersection between both Enums.

---

Or without streams:

```
List<String> enumA = new ArrayList<>();
for (Enum constant : Elements_1.values())
    enumA.add(constant.name());

List<String> enumB = new ArrayList<>();
for (Enum constant : Elements_2.values())
    enumB.add(constant.name());

enumA.retainAll(enumB);
```

---

If you want to check for only one element at runtime, I would recommend you store enumA as a static in your Enum, then implement a simple method to check the intersection with `contains()`.

Comment: Oh, thank You. But if there is any way to use nested `for (Enum constant : Enum.values())` construction? I would like to try it that way if it's possible.

Comment: There you go... Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank You very much.